# What are the grammatical phrases in this sentence?

Tags: phrases, prepositional-phrases, gerund-phrases

I'm analyzing this sentence and scanning it for prepositional, appositive and verbal phrases. In the sentence so far as I can tell there is only one prepositional and no appositive and no verbals (infinitive, gerund, participial). However, a few things do confuse me.

> He is immortal, not because he alone among creatures has an inexhaustible voice but because he has a soul, a spirit capable of compassion and sacrifice and endurance.

From what I can tell, the 'among creatures' is a prepositional phrase with 'among' being the preposition. No appositives, but I feel like a sentence like this with such an interesting structure should have more than just a single prepositional phrase.

Am I missing something here? What other phrases exist here?

Comment: _Soul_ and _spirit_ are in apposition.  _Capable of compassion ..._ is a verbal phrase. _Of compassion and ..._ is a prepositional phrase modifying _capable_. BTW, that's an odd bunch of things to be looking for. Your teacher must be a bit unusual.

Comment: What about all the noun phrases and determiner phrases? ;) This question is basically unanswerable unless you're more specific about which syntactic theory you use or which exact phrases you're looking for. If you don't think there are any verbal phrases then what are the phrases with *is* and *has* at their roots?

Comment: @JohnLawler Isn't *capable of compassion* an adjective phrase? (I know it's a reduced relative clause here ...). Or does verbal phrase mean something else? Sorry if that's a dumb question ...

Comment: *Because ... endurance* would be a prepositional phrase according to some writers like Huddleston & Pullum (CaGEL, 2002), with *because* being the preposition, but it's a bit of a contentious analysis ...

Comment: @Araucaria: _capable of compassion_ is a predicate adjective, and therefore the head of a verb phrase. As a predicate adjective, it requires an auxiliary _be_, which has been deleted here by _Whiz_-Deletion, producing the reduced VP. It works just the same as _looking for compression_ or _a man for all seasons_; they can all be produced by reducing a relative clause. It might be that "verbal phrase" means something different to some people from _Verb Phrase_, but further deponent sayeth not. [This is what ***I*** mean by "Verb Phrase"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler states in the comments:

> *Soul* and *spirit* are in apposition. *Capable of compassion ...* is a verbal phrase. *Of compassion and ...* is a prepositional phrase modifying *capable*.
>
> *capable of compassion* is a predicate adjective, and therefore the head of a verb phrase. As a predicate adjective, it requires an auxiliary be, which has been deleted here by *Whiz*-Deletion, producing the reduced VP. It works just the same as *looking for compression or a man for all seasons*; they can all be produced by reducing a relative clause. It might be that "verbal phrase" means something different to some people from *Verb Phrase*, but further deponent sayeth not. [This is what I mean by "Verb Phrase"](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/VPguide.pdf). [- John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)